# why doesn't (list1[-1]+=list2.pop(0))+=list2 work in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of strings that, in a better world, would be one list. I need to concatenate the lists, but the last element of the first list needs to be concatenated with the first element of the second list. So these guys:

```
list1 = ["bob", "sal"]
list2 = ["ly", "nigel"]
```

needs to become

```
out = ["bob", "sally", "nigel"]
```

So this isn't hard, but I'm wondering why my one liner doesn't work?

```
out = (list1[-1] += list2.pop(0)) += list2
```

Why isn't this equivalent to

```
out =  list1[-1]+=list2.pop(0)
out += list2
```

?

I have to do this a large percentage of the time through some 400K records. So if anyone has a better way to do this, then I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove all those `+=` operators, they don't make sense here. If you want to use them as a replacement for `a.extend(b)`, then remember, that they cannot be used as an expression. This command modifies the `a` list, but does not return anything. So `c = a.extend(b)` gives nothing to `c`.

Try this instead (it even does not modify original lists!):

```
out = list1[:-1] + [ list1[-1] + list2[0] ] + list2[1:]
```

returns what you want.

- `list1[:-1]` is a list from list1 without the last element.
- `list1[-1]` is the last element from list1.
- `list2[0]` is the first element from list2.
- `list1[-1] + list2[0]` is a concatenated string.
- `[ list1[-1] + list2[0] ]` is a list with one element (concatenated string).
- `list2[1:]` is a list from list2 without the first element.

Answer (score 3):

Assignments in Python are not operators that can be used within expressions.  They are statement-level syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one-liner, here's what I'd do:

```
(','.join(list1)+','.join(list2)).split(',')
```

Comment: Doesn't work correctly if you have commas anywhere in the strings within the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of @eumiros answer, on what is happening there,  you can acomplish what you want 
in a single statement with:

```
out = list1[:-1] + [list1[-1] + list2[0]] + list2[1:]
```

"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Answer (score 0):

I would not normally leave broken pieces of data around but would fix in place:

```
>>> list1 = ["bob", "sal"]
>>> list2 = ["ly", "nigel"]
>>> fix = [list1.pop()+list2.pop(0)]
>>> list1
['bob']
>>> fix
['sally']
>>> list2
['nigel']
>>> fixed = list1 + fix + list2
>>> fixed
['bob', 'sally', 'nigel']
```

Same time getting rid of those obvious list1 and list2 variable names with something readable.